# Trouble installing android-sdk using ubuntu-make

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-make

On running the following command to install android-sdk on Ubuntu 16.04 amd-64,

```
umake android android-sdk
```

I obtained the error

```
ERROR: Couldn't find android-sdk-linux in tarball
```

ubuntu-make version is 16.11.1

Comment: I have the same problem and opened a bug report in https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/392